# How to add a list of composables as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Im trying to pass a list of Composables, in this case Columns, as a parameter to later populate a view, for that I'm adding the parameter **List<@Composable (ColumnScope.() -> Unit)>** on a composable function and populating a List with simple Columns.

The problem I'm having is that the Columns generate a **Type mismatch**

```
Required:
List<ColumnScope.() → Unit>
Found:
List<Unit>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Here I'll provide my code.

```
@Composable
fun LotsOfColumns() {
    ColumnListSample(
        myColumns = listOf(
            Column {}, 
            Column {}
        )
    )
}

@Composable
fun ColumnListSample(
    myColumns: List<@Composable (ColumnScope.() -> Unit)>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Composable fun LotsOfColumns() {
    ColumnListSample(
        myColumns = listOf(
            { Column {} },
            { Column {} }
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I do this by wrapping **@Composable functions** inside a data class or a class then pass that class with a `List`

```
data class TutorialSectionModel(
    val title: String,
    val action: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    val description: String,
    val tags: List<String> = listOf(),
    val tagColor: Color = DefaultListColor,
    var expanded: Boolean = false
)
```

And create a list of that class that contains that Composables and i pass them to my LazyColumn.

```
val tutorialList = mutableListOf<List<TutorialSectionModel>>()
```

Use it with LazyColumn

```
        LazyColumn(

            content = {

                items(
                    items = tutorialList,
                    key = {
                        it.title
                    }
                ) { item: TutorialSectionModel ->

                    var isExpanded by remember(key1 = item.title) { mutableStateOf(item.expanded) }

                    TutorialSectionCard(
                        model = item,
                        onClick = {
                            navigateToTutorial(item.title)
                        },
                        onExpandClicked = {
                            item.expanded = !item.expanded
                            isExpanded = item.expanded
                        },
                        expanded = isExpanded
                    )
                }
            }
```

You can pass your `@Composable (ColumnScope.() -> Unit` to a class you created same way.

Maybe not in your question scope, the way wrapping inside a class helps passing this list to a ViewModel and i use this action or Composables as navigation target too instead of writing tens of
composable navigation routes.

```
    // Set navigation route as title of tutorial card
    // and invoke @Composable inside lambda of this card.
    mainViewModel.tutorialList.forEach { list ->
        list.forEach { model ->
            composable(route = model.title) { navBackEntryStack ->
                // This column is used for setting navigation padding since
                // NavHost only has statusBarsPadding to let main screen list have
                // inset at the bottom with WindowInsetsSides.Bottom
              Column(Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()) {
                  //  These are @Composable screens such as Tutorial2_1Screen()
                  model.action?.invoke()
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's declared:

```
@Composable
fun SettingsRow(
    modifier: Modifier? = null,
    horizontalArrangement: Arrangement.Horizontal = Arrangement.Start,
    verticalAlignment: Alignment.Vertical = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    children: List<@Composable RowScope.() -> Unit>,
    onClick: () -> Unit
)
```

This is how composable list passed as parameter:

```
SettingsRow(
    children = listOf(
        { Icon(Icons.Rounded.Done, contentDescription = "Done") },
        {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f)) {
                Text(text = config.name)
            }
        }
    )
)
```

This is how the `children` is used in `SettingsScreen` composable.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f)) {
    children.map { it ->
        it()
    }
}
```